# Getting Error while creating Hive External Table on top of Hbase Table

Tags: hive, hbase

I am creating hive external table on top of Hbase table so that I can analyse data using Hive but as I run the script for creating table using Hbase serde it throws error 'Hbase Table doesn't Exists.Kindly check the attached image of error.Kindly guide.

[image]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HBase table has created in **specific namespace (network_tower)** then you are not mentioning correct syntax how to access a **table from specific namespace in HBase**.

In tblproperties include **:(colon)** to access a table from HBase namespace instead of **.(period)**

> TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "**network_tower:orders**")

**Sample HBase-Hive ddl:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(rowkey string, ...)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:...")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "network_tower:orders");
```

As you are creating external table so the HBase table needs to be existed already,

Make sure the table exists in HBase.

```
bash$ hbase shell
hbase(main):> scan 'network_tower:orders',{LIMIT=>1}
```

Comment: Hi Shu, really thank you for your answer,I will definately try this.